# A simple proof that non negative polynomials have even degree

Tags: polynomials, optimization, convex-optimization

I am looking for a simple proof that a non-negative polynomial in n variables has always even degree. I have proved it but using  Artin's Theorem ( Every non-negative polynomial is the sum of squares of rational functions), but I think that there are simpler proofs.

Comment: Are you thinking about polynomials in a single variable - in which case the leading term (odd) eventually dominates for large absolute values of the variable.

Comment: A post on [mathoverflow.se]: [A simple proof that non negative polynomials have even degree](https://mathoverflow.net/q/362885). There is one answer, however, the question was closed.